# Baseline of \sqrt

Tags: alignment, sqrt

How is it possible to change the baseline of a root but not sliding the radicand below it? My aim is something like the image (which I constructed by manipulating the screenshot of the MWE). From esthetical aspects the root is to "tall" but that is another problem. With the solutions of #49833 I do not succeed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
5\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{24}} \quad \text{and} \quad \sqrt{5\tfrac{5}{24}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:
With the MWE above I get this and here at first glance the left part may be understood as the 5th root.

[image]

Comment: Did you also see this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49857/47927 ? But doesn't your picture suggest that you also want to shift the fraction as well? So, it would require a lot of shifting actually. Math-mode is normally typeset so that everything is aligned to the horizontal center of the formula (which is quite reasonable because fractions can be stacked to whatever height and depth).

Comment: @Jasper Habicht I saw this, that's what I mean by #49833. I understand your point, but see my edit. Maybe there are better ideas to avoid this.

Comment: I would not read this as the 5th root at all. But to make it clearer, you could insert a `\cdot` maybe. (Wouldn't this be more correct anyways, since there are just two numbers placed next to each other, in contrast to the right where you have a mixed number under the root sign?)

Comment: `5\,\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{24}}` could be a solution, as well as `5\sqrt{5/24}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid shifting up. I don't think that the 5 can be confused with the root index, but that's opinion.

You may add a thin space `\,` or an explicit multiplication symbol, in case you really feel the construction to be ambiguous.

I also show how to raise to the baseline, but the result is not really pretty nor in accord to any known practice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
5\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{24}} \quad
5\,\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{24}} \quad
\sqrt[5]{\tfrac{5}{24}} \quad
5\cdot\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{24}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
5
\scalebox{1}[1.2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    $\sqrt{\vphantom{|}\hphantom{\tfrac{5}{24}}}$%
  }%
}
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{\depth}{$\tfrac{5}{24}$}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]